# PyQt - Make QAction checkable even if it is disabled

Tags: python, pyqt

I want a QAction that has a slightly altered behavior. I want the QAction to only emit a signal whenever it is checked and also, I want its checkbox to always be checkable, even if the QAction is has been disabled. For example, if you set a QAction to setEnabled(False), you can't click the QAction or check/uncheck it. I like that it can't be clicked anymore but dislike that I can't toggle the checkbox inside the QAction. Is it possible to modify it to get what I'm looking for?

I attached an example file, below. The goal is to make some solution where QAction is set to disabled (setEnabled(False)) but the user can still check/uncheck it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''An example file with a QAction that stays checkable.'''

# IMPORT STANDARD LIBRARIES
import sys

# IMPORT THIRD-PARTY LIBRARIES
from Qt import QtWidgets
from Qt import QtCore


class AlwaysOpenAction(QtWidgets.QAction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlwaysOpenAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.toggled.connect(self.printout)

    def printout(self):
        if self.isChecked():
            print('Checkbox was checked')


class WindowTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    '''A basic window.'''

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        '''Init the window.'''
        super(WindowTest, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=self)
        self.menu = self.menubar.addMenu('Some menu')

        action = AlwaysOpenAction('something', self.menu)
        action.setCheckable(True)
        action.setEnabled(False)

        self.menu.addAction(action)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.menubar)
        self.resize(500, 400)


def main():
    '''Do the window test.'''
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowTest()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: May I know what is it good for? Maybe we could figure out a different solution for your problem, because this doesn't sound like expected behavior of `QActions`.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Basically, I have an application that has a menu which contains a number of tools. Some of the tools have dependencies and others don't. Some tools have dependencies that set themselves up, automatically, and so the tool itself doesn't need to be pressed like the others every time in order to run. They just need to load/unload once.


In cases where they don't have any runtime behavior, I'd want a way to turn the dependencies on/off without actually running the click function of a QAction but also show to the user (usually just by graying it out or making it unclickable)

Comment: You could explain me better, your question is very confusing.

Comment: What kind of events do you want the `QAction` to issue a signal to?

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer. It's not an issue of signals. I need a different behavior out of QAction than what it does, by default. if QAction is disabled, you can't click on it or check/uncheck its state. I need to be able to still check/uncheck it even if it's disabled

Comment: And why do you have to use `setEnabled (False)`?

Comment: The purpose of `setEnabled(False)` is to disable all type of events on the `QAction`

Comment: Doesn't have to be. Honestly I don't care what the method to use as long as it's idiomatic to other programmers and visually lets the user know "this isn't clickable". Sounds like you have a better idea - what would you do instead?

Comment: Just want to change the color of `QAction`?

Comment: Yes. It also has to not be clickable (The QAction. The checkbox should still be clickable)

Comment: You want the `checkbox` that is inside the `QAction` can be used even when this `QAction` is disabled?

Comment: I understand what you want ... in a moment I will publish your answer.

Comment: That's what I'm doing already, using a QWidgetAction. I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I personally cannot find desired solution. Once `QAction` is disabled, no signals (except `hovered`) are sent and I don't know how to override it.

Comment: Following up on this post, since I haven't heard back. Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

since you want to be able to still click in the QAction to check and uncheck I don't think it would be necessary to disable the QAction. Instead you could just change the appearance of it.
Have you tried mess around with Stylesheet?

Just try to add this simple line in your code:

```
self.menu.setStyleSheet("""color: gray;""")
```

So what I'm trying to say here is that you can change the style of your qaction according to your will.

You can also try something more elaborated and more specific, the above line will change every text inside your menu to gray, you can specify what kind of object you want to change the font color, and much more, for example:

```
self.menu.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton{background-color: red}""")
```

and so on...

You could try some other approaches to achieve what you want, sometimes we just get stuck in something and there are other ways to do the same. Have a fast look in this piece of code I modified that makes something similar to what you want, I think ")

```
'''An example file with a QAction that stays checkable.'''

# IMPORT STANDARD LIBRARIES
import sys

# IMPORT THIRD-PARTY LIBRARIES
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidgetAction



class CheckBox(QCheckBox):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(CheckBox, self).__init__()
        self.update_color()
        self.setText(name)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.update_color()
        super(CheckBox, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def update_color(self):
        if self.isChecked():
            self.setStyleSheet("color: gray;")
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet("")

class WindowTest(QWidget):

    '''A basic window.'''

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        '''Init the window.'''
        super(WindowTest, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(parent=self)
        self.menu = self.menubar.addMenu('Some menu')
        self.menu.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        self.widget_action = QWidgetAction(self)
        self.button = CheckBox("some")
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setFixedSize(100, 20)
        self.widget_action.setDefaultWidget(self.button)
        self.menu.addAction(self.widget_action)
        self.setFixedSize(500,200)


def main():
    '''Do the window test.'''
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowTest()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Since the first example of stylesheet I gave u has a flaw because QAction is not a Widget so I cant really change its stylesheet(it doesn't have one) so I had to change the menu stylesheet what would affect everyone else. This second example uses QCheckBox which is a widget so I can specifically change its stylesheet and I have a better control above each one item from menu :D**

Comment: Is there a way in QSS to disable the click functionality of a widget? Maybe you just meant to make a simple example but a color change won't be enough because the button on the QAction would still be clickable, even if the color is changed

Comment: I just edited my example using another thing instead of QAction, this one you could enable and disable whenever you want. I think you should have something to manage your items when enable and disable it, when necessary.

Comment: Tell me in wich way you want your status. If It's checked can it be clicked? If it's checked is it gray or black? what are all the status case. Can you give me that so I could understand better what behavior you are looking for?

Comment: The editted solution that you posted doesn't work with self.menu.setTearOffEnabled(True).

In truth, I have a similar set up to the one you posted already but the users who test it aren't satisfied with it because they want the tearoff. Basically a disabled action in the menu just has two states. Check on, check off. An enabled action has still only two states, check on, check off, too, but it can be clicked do to X. The only difference is that the enabled one can be clicked. My solution uses a checkbox and a pushbutton and QWidgetAction, like yours, but tearOff doesn't work.

Comment: It definitely seems like a bug to me, and it is, saw in some forums people asking about it and a bug reported on qt's forum. I'm trying to work it around but not so successful so far.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if you saw my link to it earlier but I found a bug (years old so maybe it's been addressed) https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1017.

Please let me know if you find anything, on your end